# DependencyProperty и UserControl, есть ли ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Здравствуйте. Есть вопрос. У готовых контролов есть свойства выставленные наружу через `DP`.
Например,

```
  <WpfToolkit:ColumnSeries  ItemsSource="{Binding spectr_ListG}"/>
```

Скорее всего у этого контрола есть `ViewModel` в качестве отдельного класса.

1. Работают ли такие контролы с  выставленными наружу `DP` объявленные в `*.xaml.cs` во `ViewModel`? Если да, то как они их получают из  `*.xaml.cs` в `ViewModel`.
2. Или у таких контролов вся логика хранится в `*.xaml.cs` и нет никакой `ViewModel`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Цитата Работают ли такие контролы с выставленными наружу DP объявленные в *.xaml.cs во ViewModel? Если да, то как они их получают из  *.xaml.cs в ViewModel.

Можно передать их во `вью-модель` через `вью` узнав его `DataContext`

xaml:

```
 <UserControl1 MyProperty="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>
```

xaml.cs:

```
 public int MyProperty
 {
     get { return (int)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
     set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
 }     
 public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(int), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(null, MyProperty_PropertyChangedCallback));  

 //обработчик изменения DP
 public static void MyProperty_PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     var vm = this.DataContext as VM;
     if (vm != null)
     {
         //здесь передаем DP в нашу VM
         vm.MyProperty = MyProperty;
     }       
 }
```

VM:

```
class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //.. реалиазация INPC

    private int _myProperty;
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return _myProperty; }
        set { _myProperty = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("MyProperty"); }
    }

}
```

Comment: А зачем `MyProperty_PropertyChangedCallback`? По идее, `Binding` работает автоматически в обе стороны. Вы просто пишете `MyProperty="{Binding MyProperty}"`.

Comment: @VladD Ну.., а как это свойство обновится во VM?

Comment: `Binding` должен обновлять в обе стороны, насколько я понимаю. При обновлении свойства в VM обновится свойство в контроле, а при обновления свойства в контроле обновится связанное свойство в VM.

Comment: @VladD Я привязываюсь к `DP`, который находится во `view` и хочу получить значение уже во VM. Я же не могу выставить `DP` из `VM` во `View`?

Comment: Нет, но это и не нужно. Попробуйте ваш же код, только уберите `new PropertyMetadata(null, MyProperty_PropertyChangedCallback)`, и замените `{Binding SomeProperty}` на `{Binding MyProperty}`.

Comment: @VladD я вас понял)) Возникло недопонимание. Я хотел иметь возможность передавать данные между разными `VM` через `view`, но это было давно, на момент написания вопроса, так я уже не делаю)

Comment: Аааа! Понятно. Ну обмен данными через View по идее не лучшая затея, т. к. VM не должна вообще предполагать, что к ней подключён View. Но в принципе можно. Проще всего связать две DP во View через code-behind (как в вашем ответе), и забиндить обе на разные свойства VM.

Answer (score 1):

Вряд ли контролы сделаны в паттерне `mvvm` ergo `ViewModel` у них нет.